# Wordpress "Medicure" theme Visual Content Composer not working on a live site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using "Medicure" theme for Wordpress and it has a feature for creating the main page layout called "Visual Content Composer".

The problem is when I install the theme on a local machine everything works fine, but when I transfer the site on a live site this feature won't work and in Google developer tool on console tab I get this error:

[image: 404 error Screenshot]

I tried changing permissions of the files and folders on the host but nothing happened.
If anyone could help me I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
There was a rule on the htaccess file in public_html folder that blocked my POST request from the ajax and responded with a 404 error.